# Answer to this compound interest problem?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic, word-problem

Can anybody help me with this problem?

> When will a payment of 300,000 galleons cancel Mr. Weasley’s liabilities
>   to Gringott’s Bank of 100,000 galleons due after 2 years and
>   150,000 galleons due after 5 years if money is worth at an effective
>   rate of 12%?

I'm stuck at the given.

Comment: Are you familiar with the concept of *Present Value*? Calculate the PV of the commitment. Then the PV of $300000$ at time $T$ should be equal to the PV of the commitment.

Comment: @AndréNicolas so I should look for the PV of 100,000 due after 2 years AND the PV of 150,000 due after 5 years (both with j = 0.12, m = 1)?

Comment: Yes, then add them. Call the result $A$. We want $(300000)(1.12)^{-T}=A$.  Solve for $T$.

Comment: I got, A = 389,791.25. Then I plugged in the values in (300000)(1.12)−T=A. So I got $$389,791.25 = (300,000)(1.12)^-T$$ But I think I'm getting the wrong answer because I got T = .99

Comment: Your $A$ is not right. The PV is $100000(1.12)^{-2}+150000(1.12)^{-5}$, much less than the value of $A$ you wrote down.  By the way, what is the answer that they give?

Comment: Ohhh, my bad. I used positive 2 and 5 as exponents. So it would end up being, A = 164,833.41? Then T = 1.06?

Comment: I have not checked your calculation of $A$. In solving $300000(1.12){-T}=A$, you are miscalculating. We want $(1.12)^T=(300000/A)$. Now use logarithms.

Comment: Oh I seeee. From $T = \cfrac {ln \left(\cfrac {300,000}{164,833.41}\right)}{ln (1.12)}$,  I got $T \approx 5.28$. I hope that's correct!!!! :(

Comment: Looks about right. Maybe I will write a formal answer, since the PV concept is important.

Comment: Okie dokes. I will try to do more checks as well, and will keep a lookout for your response in case you have the time to reply, still! Hehe. But thank you so much for taking the time to respond to my questions!!!!!! :) Thank you for the kindness and patience, sir! You are helping me get over my math phobia.

Comment: And if you have the time, I have another problem (but I've already done the calculations till the final answer). Only if you have the time!!! http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1856028/can-you-check-if-my-final-answer-correct-compound-interest-problem?noredirect=1#comment3799819_1856028 Heheeee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The combined **Present Value** $A$ of the two payment commitments is given by
$$A=100000(1.12)^{-2}+150000(1.12)^{-5}.$$
We want to find the time $T$ such that the PV of a payment of $300000$ at time $T$ is equal to $A$. So we want to solve the equation
$$300000(1.12)^{-T}=A.$$
Equivalently, we want to solve
$$(1.12)^T=\frac{300000}{A}.$$
Take the logarithm of both sides.