# Can you check if my final answer correct? (Compound interest problem)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic, word-problem

## Problem:

> Blooie has the following obligations: 100,000 due after 4 years without
>   interest and 200,000 dues after 3 years with accumulated interest
>   at ($j_1$ = 0.12, $m_1$ = 2). Blooie wants to pay a certain amount after 2
>   years and then double this amount after another year. What should
>   he pay after 2 years if all amounts are covered by an interest rate of
>   ($j_2$ = 0.08, $m_2$ = 2)?

## My solution:

#### Given:

**Loans**                **Payments**      **Creditor**
$P_1$ = 100,000    $P_2$ = 200,000   x (in 2 years)     $j_2$ = 0.08
j = 0        j = 0.12      2x (in 3 years)    $m_2$ = 2
m = 0       m = 2
$t_1$ = 0        $t_2$ = 3

#### Solve for future values

$$F_1 = 100,000$$
$$F_2 = 200,000(1+ \frac{0.12}{2})^{2(3)}\approx 283,703.82$$

#### Solve for values of loans at reference time

$$Loan 1 = 100,000(1+ \frac{0.08}{2})^{-2(2)}\approx 85,480.42$$
$$Loan 2 = 283,703.82(1+ \frac{0.08}{2})^{-2(1)}\approx 262,300.13$$

#### Add values of loans

$$Value of loans = 85,480.42 + 262,300.13 \approx 347,780.55$$

#### Compute for values of payments at reference time

$$Payment 1 = X$$
$$Payment 2 = 2x(1+ \frac{0.08}{2})^{-2(1)}$$
$$= 2x(0.9246)$$
$$\approx 2x(0.9246)+x$$

#### Write equation of values

$$Value of loans = Value of payments$$
$$2x(0.9246)+x = 347,780.55$$
$$x \approx 122,062.53$$

### Final Answer:

Blooie should pay 122,062.53 after 2 years.

Comment: $F_1$ and $F_2$ are both calculated for $t=4$. Then you  discounted both to $t=2$ (reference time). Thus in both cases, Loan1 and Loan2, the factor is $(1.04)^{-2\cdot 2}$